# Install Windows Update file (*.msu) without having Windows update service activated

Tags: windows, windows-installer, installation

I want to install a specific Windows Update file (.msu) on a device which is running on Windows 7 embedded. The msu file is available and the automated installation is running the right commands, but I have a problem:

On the device, the Windows update service is disabled. This is a requirement from the device image, this service should not be activated (not even for the time of the installation). If I try to install the msu file without this service, an error occurs "The service cannot be started, either because it is disabled or ...".

My question is : Does anyone know a possibility to install a msu file without having the Windows Update Service enabled?

Comment: What command are you currently using to install it?  Have you tried dism as well as wusa?  Failing all else, an offline install should work, i.e., boot to WinPE or similar.

Comment: I use a wusa call for the update. I already checked DISM.exe commands, but my problem is that on the device image, there is an "old" dism.exe which does not know the argument "/Add-Package", so it was not possible for me to use this.

Maybe I can update the DISM.exe during installation, I will try this.

Comment: Problem solved. Using DISM.exe works if the right command is used. Additionally, it is important that MSU files cannot be installed using DISM.exe with /Online mode. You have to unpack the msu file, the resulting *.cab file can then be installed using DISM.exe without enabled Windows update service. See [link](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askcore/2011/02/15/how-to-use-dism-to-install-a-hotfix-from-within-windows/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From comment:

> Using DISM.exe works if the right command is used. 
>   Additionally, it is important that **MSU files cannot be installed using DISM.exe with `/Online`** mode.
>
> You have to unpack the msu file, the resulting *.cab file can then be installed using DISM.exe without enabled Windows update service. See [How to use DISM to install a hotfix from within Windows](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askcore/2011/02/15/how-to-use-dism-to-install-a-hotfix-from-within-windows/)

I'll quote the blog post here:

> The purpose of this blog is to give you the steps to install a hotfix
>   (or any other “package”) on the currently running operating system
>   using the Deployment Image Servicing and Management (DISM) command.
>
> ...
>
> The command-line switch to install a package is “/Add-Package.”
>   ... the file name is “Windows6.1-KB976571-v2-x64.msu.” 
>   ... you would assume that following
>   syntax would work:
>
> ```
> DISM.exe /Online /Add-Package /PackagePath:c:\kb976571\Windows6.1-KB976571-v2-x64.msu
> ```
>
> You will see the following snippet if you review the file
>   c:\windows\logs\dism\dism.log:
>
> > ...
> >
> > 2010-09-02 20:33:58, Error DISM DISM Package Manager: PID=7116
> >     **DISM does not support installing MSU files online**. –
> >     CMsuPackage::Install(hr:0x80070032)
>
> ...
>
> The answer is found in defining what a Microsoft Update Standalone
>   Package (MSU) file is and how you would do this in the previous
>   command-line tool, Package Manager (Pkgmgr.exe).
>
> You had to extract the contents of a MSU file and instead use the .CAB
>   file of the package in order to install or uninstall using the Package
>   Manager tool
>   (http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;940410).
>
> So try this approach:
>
> ...
>
> 2. Use the following command to extract the contents of the MSU file:
>
>    ```
>    Expand –F:* c:\kb976571\Windows6.1-KB976571-v2-x64.msu c:\temp\976571
>    ```
>
> ... multiple files, which included the Windows6.1-KB976571-v2-x64.cab
>   file.
>
> Now try the following command:
>
> ...
>
> ```
> DISM.exe /Online /Add-Package /PackagePath:c:\temp\976571\Windows6.1-KB976571-v2-x64.cab
> ```
>
> ... (or) ...
>
> ```
> start /wait DISM.exe /Online /Add-Package /PackagePath:c:\temp\976571\Windows6.1-KB976571-v2-x64.cab /Quiet /NoRestart
> ```